# Does receiving a hadd in this world cause the sin to be forgiven in the hereafter?

Tags: hudud

I have heard from somewhere that the hudod punishment being carried out on you in this world acts as an expiation for the sin committed (e.g. let's say your hand was cut off, then that would mean that Allah would forgive you for stealing). Is this true and is this the view of most scholars?

Answer (score 2):

> "‘Ubada b. as-Samit reported that God's messenger said when a number
> of his Companions were around him, “Swear allegiance to me on the
> basis that you will not associate anything with God, or steal, or
> commit fornication, or kill your children, or produce slander which
> you yourselves have falsely fabricated, or be disobedient concerning
> what is good. If any of you fulfils his promise, God will undertake
> his reward **but if anyone perpetrates any of these things and is
> punished for it in this world, it will be an atonement for him.** If,
> however, anyone perpetrates any of those things and God conceals it
> regarding him, the matter lies in God’s hands; if He wishes He will
> forgive him, and if He wishes He will punish him.” So we swore
> allegiance to him on that basis." (Bukhari and Muslim.) (Translation by James Robson)
>
> Grade: Muttafaqun 'alayh (Zubair `Aliza'i)

[Reference](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:18)

and Allah knows best.